# Select statement with a dynamic group by clause

Tags: oracle

How possible to group records conditionally? For example I have records with *FLOW_NUMBER* column, values 1, 2, 3. When *FLOW_NUMBER* value is 1, I want to group this records, but when *FLOW_NUMBER* is 2 or 3, I don't want to group.

```
SELECT
    LISTAGG(DISTINCT PRODORD, ',')  PRODORD,
    SUM(QTY) AS QTY
FROM (
    SELECT
        1 AS FLOW_NUMBER,
        'A' AS PRODORD,
        1 AS QTY
    FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        1 AS FLOW_NUMBER,
        'B' AS PRODORD,
        1 AS QTY
    FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        1 AS FLOW_NUMBER,
        'C' AS PRODORD,
        1 AS QTY
    FROM DUAL

    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        2 AS FLOW_NUMBER,
        'A' AS PRODORD,
        1 AS QTY
    FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        2 AS FLOW_NUMBER,
        'B' AS PRODORD,
        1 AS QTY
    FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        2 AS FLOW_NUMBER,
        'C' AS PRODORD,
        1 AS QTY
    FROM DUAL

    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        3 AS FLOW_NUMBER,
        'A' AS PRODORD,
        1 AS QTY
    FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        3 AS FLOW_NUMBER,
        'B' AS PRODORD,
        1 AS QTY
    FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        3 AS FLOW_NUMBER,
        'C' AS PRODORD,
        1 AS QTY
    FROM DUAL
)
GROUP BY FLOW_NUMBER -- bad group by clause
```

[image: Example]

There is example photo of group by which I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(flow,1,INSTR(flow,'/')-1) AS flow, LISTAGG(prodorder,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY prodorder) AS prodorders, SUM(qty) AS qty
FROM (
    SELECT CASE WHEN flow=1 THEN '1/' ELSE to_CHAR(flow)||'/'||ROWNUM END AS flow,
        prodorder, qty FROM DATA
)
GROUP BY flow;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anyway to achieve it except using 2 query combined with UNION ALL clause -

```
SELECT FLOW_NUMBER, LISTAGG(DISTINCT PRODORD, ',')  PRODORD,
    SUM(QTY) AS QTY
FROM temp
  WHERE FLOW_NUMBER = 1
GROUP BY FLOW_NUMBER
  UNION ALL
SELECT FLOW_NUMBER, PRODORD,
       QTY
FROM temp
  WHERE FLOW_NUMBER <> 1;
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/8gnwGCIZ?hide=8)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
select
substr(fn,1,decode(instr(fn,','),0,1000,instr(fn,','))-1) flow_number,
prodord, qty
from (SELECT
    case when FLOW_NUMBER=1 then to_char(flow_number) else  to_char(flow_number)||','||rownum end fn,
    LISTAGG(DISTINCT PRODORD, ',')  PRODORD,
    SUM(QTY) AS QTY
FROM (
    SELECT
        1 AS FLOW_NUMBER,
        'A' AS PRODORD,
        1 AS QTY
    FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        1 AS FLOW_NUMBER,
        'B' AS PRODORD,
        1 AS QTY
    FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        1 AS FLOW_NUMBER,
        'C' AS PRODORD,
        1 AS QTY
    FROM DUAL

    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        2 AS FLOW_NUMBER,
        'A' AS PRODORD,
        1 AS QTY
    FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        2 AS FLOW_NUMBER,
        'B' AS PRODORD,
        1 AS QTY
    FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        2 AS FLOW_NUMBER,
        'C' AS PRODORD,
        1 AS QTY
    FROM DUAL

    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        3 AS FLOW_NUMBER,
        'A' AS PRODORD,
        1 AS QTY
    FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        3 AS FLOW_NUMBER,
        'B' AS PRODORD,
        1 AS QTY
    FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        3 AS FLOW_NUMBER,
        'C' AS PRODORD,
        1 AS QTY
    FROM DUAL
)
GROUP BY case when FLOW_NUMBER=1 then to_char(flow_number) else  to_char(flow_number)||','||rownum end);
```

I used rownum here, but you can probably replace it by other things (e.g. rowid, if the data is from a table, just be sure to have a unique value)

Comment: Little bit complex but good logic.